# Issues with git on Mac

Tags: ios, bash, terminal

I installed the command line interface from GitHub's site.  I created a new folder to pull files down to and tried to initialize my folder by issuing the command git init but I get command not found.  Next I ran `echo $PATH` and I got:

```
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin
```

so I created a profile by issuing the command

```
$ touch .bash_profile
```

and then I edited the profile

```
$ open -e .bash_profile.
```

Finally I exported a new path so git could be found

```
$ export PATH=/usr/local/git/bin
```

Finally when I run `echo $PATH` I get `/usr/local/git/bin` but I still get the same error as before when I try to initialize my directory and now basic commands like 'ls' don't work.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You stomped out your path! Change it to

```
 export PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/git/bin
```

Comment: whoops!  when I try and reopen that profile I get "command not found"  How do I get back to the profile file

Comment: I am able to see the results of echo $PATH but I get command not found when I try to issue command open -e .bash_profile

Comment: Ok, I ran this and things seem to be back to normal.  export PATH="/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin"